# Java + Eclipse: Synchronize stdout and stderr

Tags: java, eclipse, synchronization, stdio

I use Eclipse. When I have an application like this:

```
write 20 times 'Hello World\n' to stdout
write 'ERROR\n' to stderr
write 5 times 'Hello  World\n' to stdout
```

The output looks many times like this:

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
...
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
ERROR
```

Is there a way to synchronize these two output streams? Of course without waiting a few milliseconds after the block of 20 times `Hello World` and waiting a few milliseconds after printing `ERROR`.

Answer (score 8):

### Believe it or not, flushing is not a solution here....

If a stream leads to "an abstraction provided by the underlying operating system" (e.g. a disk drive or console) then remaining bytes "are passed to the operating system for writing; it does not guarantee that they are actually written..." (see [the OutputStream documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush())). The key here is that the OS can handle flushes from different streams in different orders if it so chooses.

I just had this happen in my program.  I had an error message appear between two normal message, both of which had flushed  before the error message did.

**So the question remains,** is there a built-in way to synchronize two streams?  Or do we have to handle that manually?

Answer (score 7):

For "serious" use, I prefer not writing directly to `System.out/System.err`, since it hard-codes the destination, and it also it uses the rather quirky `PrintStream` (is it a byte stream or a character stream?). If you wrap the output streams in your own `PrintWriter`, you can then set it to flush automatically - the second argument in the constructor is `auto-flush`.

E.g.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
PrintWriter err = new PrintWriter(System.err, true);

out.println("Hello world");
//this will flush after writing the end of line
```

See

- [java.io.PrintWriter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html), javadoc Java SE 6
- [Differences between PrintWriter and PrintStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822005/java-difference-between-printstream-and-printwriter), SO question

Comment: *"is it a byte stream or a character stream?"*. It is clearly a byte stream.  The methods that write characters, strings, numbers, etc do implicit conversions to bytes using the JVM's default charset.

Comment: @Stephen I was talking about it's client interface in java. `PrintWriter` allows for writing characters, `OutputStream` writes bytes, yet the interface provided by `PrintStream` writes both bytes and characters, but as you point out, if you write a string through the stream then you'll get bytes out the other end in the current default encoding. This is not a good thing and is an anomaly of the early jdk 1.0 design before i18n was complete, i18n brought a clear distinction between writing bytes and writing characters. Please see the second link for more on this.

Answer (score 3):

System.out and System.err are ordinary `PrintStream` objects (which provide a flush() method), so try `System.out.flush()` and `System.err.flush()`.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no reliable way to force a sync on 2 unrelated streams.

A workaround is to use only one stream: e.g. use [System.setErr()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr(java.io.PrintStream)) to redirect out to err, so that everything is printed on the error stream:

```
System.setErr(System.out);
```

Or the other way around via [System.setOut()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream))

```
System.setOut(System.err);
```

A downside of this is that it may change syntax-highlighting: e.g. some IDEs may highlight text on stderr and stdout differently

Answer (score 0):

Add a flush followed by a `Thread.sleep(1)`, 99.9% output order will be correct.

For example, this will display as expected.

```
System.out.println( "stdout 1" ); System.out.flush(); Thread.sleep( 1 );
System.err.println( "stderr 1" ); System.err.flush(); Thread.sleep( 1 );
System.out.println( "stdout 2" ); System.out.flush(); Thread.sleep( 1 );
System.err.println( "stderr 2" ); System.err.flush(); Thread.sleep( 1 );
```

The only drawback is the sleep for 1 millisecond, i.e. 1/1000 second

Comment: This horrible hack of a solution actually works. In intellij, its more like sleep 1000 - 500 wasnt enough. Useful for non-production/debugging environments