# PrintStream vs PrintWriter

Tags: java

I have searched the site and have found some answers, but i'm having trouble understanding the difference between these two classes. Can someone explain the differences between these two classes?

Comment: `PrintStream` deals with `byte`s, while `PrintWriter` deals with `char`s. That's it.

Comment: but you can use PrintStream to write strings, chars, ints, etc. Perhaps i'm misunderstanding what you mean by it deals with bytes

Comment: check http://way2java.com/io/printstream-vs-printwriter/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822005/java-difference-between-printstream-and-printwriter

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: This question is a good one, it deserves a more detailed answer, specially if you think that System.out is actually a PrintStream, and ironically not a PrintWriter, while its goal is definitely to print characters, not bytes. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822005/java-difference-between-printstream-and-printwriter which brings additional details.

Answer (score 27):

`PrintStream` was the original bridge to deal with encoding characters and other datatypes.  If you look at the javadoc for `java.io.OutputStream` you'll see methods only for writing two distinct data types: `byte` and `int`.

In early versions of the JDK (1.0.x), when you wanted to write characters, you could do one of two things, write bytes to an output stream (which are assumed to be in the system default character set):

```
outputStream.write("foobar".getBytes());
```

or wrap another `outputStream` in a `PrintStream`:

```
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
printStream.write("foobar");
```

See the difference?  `PrintStream` is handling the character conversion to bytes, as well as encoding (the constructor call above uses the system default encoding, but you could pass it as a parameter).  It also provides convenience methods for writing `double`, `boolean`, etc....

In fact `System.out` and `System.err` are defined as `PrintStream` instances.

Along comes JDK 1.1, and they realize they need a better way to deal with pure character data, since `PrintStream` still has the byte based methods for writing.  So they introduced the `Writer` abstract class to deal strictly with `char`, `String` and `int` data.

`PrintWriter` adds methods for other types like `double`, `boolean`, etc...

Nowadays `PrintWriter` also has `format()` / `printf()` methods for format printing, etc...

As a general rule, if you're writing character data, use `Writer` instances. If you're writing binary (or mixed) data use `OutputStream` instances.

Comment: The history really helps, and explains why `System.out` and `System.err` are still `PrintStream`.

Comment: If PrintWriter is really a replacement for PrintStream, then why isn't PrintStream depricated?

Answer (score 10):

From the [Javadoc for PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html):

> Prints formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream. This class implements all of the print methods found in PrintStream. It does not contain methods for writing raw bytes, for which a program should use unencoded byte streams.

Think of it this way: a `PrintStream` sits on top of some `OutputStream`. Since output streams deal with bytes rather than characters, the PrintStream *must* take responsibility for encoding characters into bytes. The OutputStream 'merely' writes the bytes out to a file/console/socket whatever.

A `PrintWriter`, on the other hand, sits on top of a `Writer`. Since the Writer is responsible for encoding characters into bytes, the PrintWriter does not do encoding. I just knows about newlines etc.  (Yes, PrintWriters do have constructors that take `File`s and `OutputStream`s, but those are simply conveniences. For example, [`PrintWriter(OutputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.OutputStream%29).

> Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing, from an existing OutputStream. This convenience constructor creates the necessary intermediate OutputStreamWriter, which will convert characters into bytes using the default character encoding.

BTW, In case you are thinking that the `PrintWriter` really doesn't have much utility, remember that both PrintWriter and PrintStream absorb `IOException`s from printing logic.

Answer (score 3):

To add Matt's answer:

I compared `PrintStream` and `PrintWriter`,
the most useful part, the constructor *`ClassName`*`(String fileName, String charsetName)` and the *print(), println(), printf()/format()* functions are supported by both classes.

The differences are:

Since `JDK1.0` vs `JDK1.1`

Constructors:

```
PrintStream(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush, String charsetName)
PrintWriter(Writer wr)
PrintWriter(Writer wr, boolean autoFlush)
```

Methods inherited from `FilterOutputStream`/`OutputStream` vs `Writer`, the difference boils down to `byte` vs `char`:

```
PrintStream.write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
PrintStream.write(byte[] buffer)
PrintStream.write(int oneByte)

PrintWriter.write(int oneChar)
PrintWriter.write(char[] buf)
PrintWriter.write(char[] buf, int offset, int count)
PrintWriter.write(String str)
PrintWriter.write(String str, int offset, int count)
```

`PrintStream.printf()` corresponds to `PrintWriter.format()`

It indeed looks like in 1.1. they thought out a better class, but could not remove the old 1.0 class without breaking existing programs.