# How to make the PrintWriter to write UTF-8?

Tags: java, utf-8, printwriter

How to make the `PrintWriter` to write UTF-8?

```
pstream = new PrintWriter(csocket.getOutputStream(), true);
String res = "some string";
pstream.println(res); // here I want to output string as UTF-8
```

Answer (score 63):

Use an `OutputStreamWriter`:

```
pstream = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    csocket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), true)
```

Comment: Note: `OutputStreamWriter` documentation recommends to use a wrapping within a BufferedWriter for efficiency

Answer (score 8):

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("file.txt");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Java: Difference between PrintStream and PrintWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822005/java-difference-between-printstream-and-printwriter) discussion.

To be quick: you can use -Dfile.encoding=utf8 JVM parameter or method suggested in the discussion (see second answer).

Comment: The JVM `file.encoding` saved me from a problem I've been having for years. Thanks @Daniil!

Answer (score 1):

```
PrintWriter out1 = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    out1 = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8),true);
} else { 
    out1 = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"), true);
}
```

Comment: question has nothing to do with android.

Answer (score 1):

Don't user PrintWriter.  If you need UTF-8 encoding, just write direct to the OutputStream.

```
csocket.getOutputStream().write(res.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: While that is possible, that does not provide one with a `Writer` what OP is likely looking for.

Comment: There are cases where `java.io.PrintWriter` cannot be avoided, such as when subclassing `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper`.

Comment: I agree with writing direct to an OutputStream that way you actually know exactly what's going on. Using wrappers in a great class hierarchy usually takes for ever to get them to work - simplicity is better.

Answer (score 0):

you can only write to file with any charset, otherwise platform default charset used see [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)