# Java: reading file and then writting data on a text file

Tags: java, file, io, readfile, writefile

How to read a file and then write the data into a .txt file in java? Below is my code. I am reading a file with extension .ivt. There are some tables in .ivt and reset is a text that describes what data is all about. I have to read the text stored in the file and then write it on a text file. I was able to get the data and write it on text file as well. But, when I open the text file and look at what is written, I see many lines of random symbols and spaces. Then, few lines are converted from English to French. I am struggling to find why this is happening. Does this problem occurs while reading data? or is there something wrong with the code?

```
package description;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileDescription
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // create variables
        ArrayList<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<>();
        String currLine;

        // create file
        File file = new File("E:\\Deep\\Personal Life\\Summer Education\\Grade 12 Physics\\Test\\Products.ivt");

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            // construct buffered reader
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
        }

        try
        {
            while((currLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // add line to the arrayList
                fileLines.add(currLine);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
        finally 
        {
            // close buffered reader
            try
            {
                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
        }

        // write ArrayList on file
        PrintWriter pw = null;

        try
        {
            pw = new PrintWriter("E:\\Deep\\Personal Life\\Summer Education\\Grade 12 Physics\\Test\\ProductsO.txt");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < fileLines.size(); i++)
        {
            pw.println(fileLines.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code seems correct. Just remember to close output writer too. Without specify anything else, you are using plaftorm encoding. I think it's an encoding problem. You can try to read and write in UTF-8 encoding.

For the buffered reader

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream("filename.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

And for the writer

```
pstream = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream("E:\\Deep\\Personal Life\\Summer Education\\Grade 12 Physics\\Test\\ProductsO.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), true);
```

To edit result, use an editor with UTF-8.

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350676/how-to-read-write-this-in-utf-8)
[Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096367/how-to-make-the-printwriter-to-write-utf-8)

Comment: I think it is encoding problem too. I got how you mentioned encoding while reading the file but, could you please explain me how writing encoding is done? The part I am confused about is - csocket.getOutputStream(). Also, how will I provide the file name to write on?